# Mocha & Chai - Test if async function throws TypeError when passed invalid param?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, mocha.js, chai

### I have this function:

```
const DEFAULT_ROLES = [
  'Director',
  'Admin',
]; // Default Policy

async function aliasIsAdmin(alias, roles = DEFAULT_ROLES) {
  const url = 'https://foobarapi.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/foo/bar/'; 

  //How to test for this throw, for example?
  if (typeof alias !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError(`Entity "alias" must be a string but got "${typeof alias}" instead.`); 
  }

  if (!Array.isArray(roles)) {
    throw new TypeError(`Entity "roles" must be an array but got "${typeof roles}" instead.`);
  } else if (roles.some((role) => typeof role !== 'string')) {
    throw new TypeError(`Entity "roles" must be an array of strings but got at least one element of type: "${typeof roles}" instead.`);
  }

  const { data } = (await axios.get(url + alias)); // Fetch roles that the alias holds.
  return data.some((role) => roles.includes(role));
}
```

### How can I use Mocha and Chai to test if the function throws when an invalid param is passed?

For example, the `async` function `aliasIsAdmin()` should throw `TypeError: Entity "alias" must be a string but got "undefined" instead.` because the `alias` param is `undefined` for that specific call.

### If I do:

```
it('throws TypeError when alias param is not typeof "string"', async () => {
    assert.throws(async function () { await aliasIsAdmin() }, TypeError, /must be string/);
});
```

### I get:

```
aliasIsAdmin
    1) throws TypeError when alias param is not typeof "string"
(node:77600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Entity "alias" must be a string 
but got "undefined" instead.
[... stacktrace continues ...]

  1) aliasIsAdmin
   throws TypeError when alias param is not typeof "string":
 AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw TypeError
  at Context.<anonymous> (test/permissions-manager-client.test.js:25:16)
  at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
  at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:130:23)
```

I can't find examples with `async` functions so I guess this is the reason why it doesn't work.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in `try/catch` since it's throwing `Error`

```js
it('throws TypeError when alias param is not typeof "string"', async () => {
    try {
        await aliasIsAdmin();
    } catch(error) {
        // Do your assertion here
        expect(error).to.be.an('error');
        expect(error.name).to.be.equal('TypeError');
        expect(error.message).to.be.equal('Entity "alias" must be a string but got "undefined" instead.');
    }
});
```

(or)

**Edit**

```js
it('throws TypeError when alias param is not typeof "string"', async () => {
    await expect(aliasIsAdmin()).to.be.rejectedWith(TypeError);
});
```

(finally)
For a more complete solution, a message can be tested:

```js
it('throws TypeError when alias param is not typeof "string"', async () => {
    await expect(aliasIsAdmin()).to.be.rejectedWith(TypeError, 'Entity "alias" must be a string but got "undefined" instead.');
});
```

Comment: How would you suggest to do the assertion?         ... `catch(error){ expect(error).to.throw(TypeError)}` won't work but `expect(error).to.be.an('error')` will. However, it would like it to be a bit more verbose. What about it testing if its a `TypeError` and making sure it's throwing the correct message? I appreciate your suggestions though, thanks a lot!

Comment: Updated my answer. Could you please try `expect(error.name).to.be.equal('TypeError');`. Hope it helps.

Comment: It works! I would hope for Chai to have some built it functionality that made it easier to test for this cases. My team is moving from Jest to Mocha + Chai and Im not loving it. After doing some research I [found some posts](https://makandracards.com/makandra/43653-javascript-don-t-throw-exceptions-from-async-functions) suggesting that conceptually, `throwing` inside an async function is not correct and that we should `reject`. I also noticed there's some Chai functionality to handle `reject` so I may be the one causing the issue due to this mentioned anti pattern. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Updated my answer (**Edit**) with exactly what you are expecting. I am not sure if that's the anti pattern since we are using `async/await` everywhere and there is no hard and fast rule to do things to be done in only one way. When it comes to testing library, I personally prefer `Jest` 

Comment: This is much better than I expected. I stumbled upon `chai-as-promised` today while researching but didn't want to use it cause it seems to be a bit outdated. I mean look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised). I mean it says, _Published 3 years ago_... isn't that a bit stale? But then again, _785,089 Weekly Downloads_ sounds like people trust it. What's your take on this? Anyway, I will keep looking for a more out-of-the-box solution but you were of great help and for now I consider you answer to be perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. **More weekly downloads!** - Reason might be, organizations/some teams in orgs are pushing people forcefully towards it . Since it's old and they are comfortable with it. Along with weekly downloads, I will also consider **stars** (Developers love towards it) in **github** while picking my library choice. For eg: [Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/stargazers) (31k+ stars) vs [Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/stargazers) (19k+ stars).

Answer (score 0):

for previous chai versions that don't have `.rejectedWith()`.
the only async test way would be handled is to wrap it inside a try catch and check `expect` the error in the catch.

```
  it('should fail', async () => {
          try{
            await failingPromise();
          }catch(err){
            expect(err).to.exist
            const { message }=err
            expect(message).to.contain("error message")
            return
          }
        //if there is no error from promise throw one here
         throw new Error("should throw")
    });
```